# TAP::Harness::JUnit does not flush output to STDOUT

Tags: perl, automated-tests, perl-prove

I am running a test script using the 
[`prove`](https://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html) utility
and
[`TAP::Harness::JUnit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/TAP::Harness::JUnit).

The output is getting buffered and not flushed immediately as compared to running with perl.

```
prove -v --timer --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit <script name>
```

The same works fine when run locally on the machine itself. Is there any option available in prove or `TAP::Harness::JUnit` to flush the output on `STDOUT` as well as capture in an XML file